# CouchbaseClient vs MemcachedClient

Tags: java, couchbase, spymemcached

I am wondering what are advantages of using one client over another. Is there possibility to use MemcachedClient to connect to client side Moxi instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance. From the memcache->Membase days, Moxi handles the routing/distribution from the Couchbase cluster side, but then all your AppServers hit individual nodes of Moxi in the cluster. We have done a lot of optimizations and improvements over this design to increase performance.

One of the improvements is with Couchbase SDK's the client's themselves have a map of cluster topology so they go directly to nodes responsible for the data rather than the Moxi routing. You will find that you get a performance boost and reduced latencies by using the Couchbase SDK's!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Scalabl3 answer take a look to : http://www.couchbase.com/memcached